# In AWS CloudFormation How can I Snapshot a "group" of virtual machines at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am configuring a Microsoft SharePoint test environment in AWS.

At a few different times during this project I would like to create
a snapshot of the state of all the machines (6).

Then be able to "jump" back to the snapshot if I need to.

(Much like you could do in VMWare Workstation)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Using Powershell, and a combination of get-ec2instance and looping through each instance via new-ec2image will get you there.

get-ec2image will allow you to check for the state of the image if you need the script to wait.